# How do you report progress from a Python UDF (for Pig)?

Tags: python, apache-pig

[Here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/udf.html#Reporting+Progress) are instructions for a Java UDF, but I'd like to do this from a Python UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get an instance of [`PigProgressable`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/physicalLayer/PigProgressable.html):

**myudf.py**

```
from time import sleep
from org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats import PigStatusReporter

@outputSchema('i:int')
def tester(foo):
    # Sleeps for a total of 3 minutes

    e = PigStatusReporter.getInstance()
    e.progress()
    sleep(60)
    e.progress()
    sleep(60)
    e.progress()
    sleep(60)
    e.progress()

    return 1
```

**myscript.pig**

```
-- Waits for 1.6 minutes before killing the job
SET mapred.task.timeout 100000 ;

register 'myudf.py' using jython as myudf ;
A = LOAD '$input' AS (foo:chararray) ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudf.tester(foo) ;
```

This example will only succeed if `e.progress()` is actually sending out a heartbeat,  otherwise it will timeout.  This test passes for me on pig 0.10.